# Powershell 4.0 and Iexpress does not launch properly

Tags: powershell

I have two files on my desktop:

```
zsnes.zip
zsnes.ps1
```

And I want to put these two into an .exe file, so I used Iexpress.exe to wrap these files and used this command:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -File "zsnes.ps1"
```

as the launch command, it works but when I remove the two files on my desktop and put them anywhere and try to execute the compiled .exe it gives me errors saying that the directory was not found. But when I put the files back on my desktop it works just fine, and it also works fine on Powershell 2.0

Im running Powershell 4.0 on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: For starters you need to add -ExecutionPolicy Bypass and -NoProfile to the powershell.exe command line to keep your script portable. Do you know whether it even gets as far as running your powershell command? Also where is Iexpress extracting your package to? does the working directory contain spaces?

Comment: Iexpress defaults the extracted files to "C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\Temp\IXP000.TMP" thanks for awnsering my question but i got it sorted out.